# definition of homology via spectra

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology, homotopy-theory

Let $K(\mathbb{Z}, n)$ denote a Eilenberg-Mac Lane space, characterized by 
$H^n(X, \mathbb{Z})=[X, K(\mathbb{Z}, n)]$ for all spaces $X$. In stable homotopy theory, the corresponding homology theory, let me denote it by $H'_*(X, \mathbb{Z})$, is defined as (I think) 
$$H'_n(X, \mathbb{Z})=colim_{i \to \infty}\ [S^{i+n}, X \wedge K(\mathbb{Z}, i)]$$

My question is why does this $H'_n(X, \mathbb{Z})$ agree with ordinary homology $H_n(X, \mathbb{Z})$?
I suppose one way is to check the above definition of $H'_*(X, \mathbb{Z})$ satisfies the Eilenberg-Steenrod axioms, and so by uniqueness of ordinary homology they are equal. But is there a more conceptual way to associate a homology class in $H_n(X, \mathbb{Z})$ to a map $f: S^{i+n} \to X \wedge K(\mathbb{Z}, i)$?

Comment: Take the pushforward of the fundamental class of $S^{i+n}$ by $f$, and use the identification (thanks to Künneth formula and Hurewicz theorem) $H_{n+i}(X \wedge K(\mathbb{Z}, i)) \cong H_n(X) \otimes H_i(K(\mathbb{Z}, i)) \cong H_n(X)$. This should give the homology class you want, I believe.

Comment: @NajibIdrissi sounds plausible. I did have a question about the isomorphism $H_{n+i}(X\wedge K(\mathbb{Z},i))\simeq H_n(X)\otimes H_i(K(\mathbb{ℤ},i))$ . From Hurewicz I can conclude $H_q(K(\mathbb{Z}, i))=0$ for $q<i$ and $q=i+1$, and $H_q(K(\mathbb{Z}, i)=\mathbb{Z}$ for $q=i$. But for $q>i+1$, are you claiming that $H_q(K(\mathbb{Z}, i))=0$? I thought the homology of the Eilenberg MacLane spaces is somewhat complicated.

Comment: It's not the case, actually, I made a mistake... Sorry.